# RenderFlex overflowed - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow

Hi i'm new in flutter and try to code my first app, I have a problem with Flutter (Dart) RenderFlex overflowed pixels.

I've tried multiple different ways of achieving this while still using a ListView.Builder but, none of them worked. What would be a better way of completing this?

my codes are here, Thanks in advance for your guidance

```
class Register extends StatefulWidget {

final Function toggleView;
Register({ this.toggleView });

@override
_RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {

final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
String error = '';
bool loading = false;

// text field state
String email = '';
String password = '';
String confirmpwd ='';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return loading ? Loading() : Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue[400],
    elevation: 0.0,
    title: Text('Sign up to Tenant App'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton.icon(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        label: Text('Sign In'),
        onPressed: () => widget.toggleView(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),
    child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'email'),
            validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() => email = val);
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'password'),
            obscureText: true,
            validator: (val) => val.length < 6 ? 'Enter a password 6+ chars long' : null,
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() => password = val);
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          TextFormField(
            decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'password'),
            obscureText: true,
            validator: (val) => val != password ? 'Password \'t match' : null,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.pink[400],
            child: Text(
              'Register',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                setState(() => loading = true);
                dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                if(result == null) {
                  setState(() {
                    loading = false;
                    error = 'Please supply a valid email';
                  });
                }
              }
            }
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 12.0),
          Text(
            error,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 14.0),
          )
         ],
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the column is receiving an unbounded height. This means that it doesn't know how big it is in its main axis, and it doesn't know where to render its children.

If you don't want to set a size for its parent container, you can use the property `mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min`.

This property tells your column to take the minimum space required and so, it doesn't matter that much the constraints that you are passing beforehand.

Secondly, as this is a `Form`, you will need to Wrap your container into a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html), to avoid the keyboard from hiding your `TextFormField`

I hope this solves your question!

Answer (score 2):

You have to just wrap your column with SingleChildScrollView, so when keyboard shows up then you can scroll also.

```
 child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: SingleChildScrollView( //added widget
          child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
```